# Comparing Objects and getting only ones that exist in all

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm building a filtering method for [Mixitup](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) and I need to be able to correctly filter against x selected parameters. (The plugin here isn't important, its how I get my correct end object)

I currently have an object, that for each unique search is sending a unique key, and its matching objects (obtained via the filter method) into my filtering function.

This is where I am lost.

I need to be able to loop over my object, and it's associated key => values (objects), and fetch out only the objects that exist in each.

For example, (instead of numbers I have jQuery objects)

```
var filter = {
    x : {1,3,5,6},
    y : {1,4,7,8},
    z : {1,9}
}
```

Based on the above example, the only returned object would be - 1 (as its the only one to exist in all three keys.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are `x`, `y` & `z` supposed to be arrays? They're objects literals with just properties at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean "the only returned _value_ would be `1` (as its the only one to exist in all three _arrays_)"? Wait, why are they jQuery objects? I dont' think they are btw. They're not any kind of JS structure.

Comment: The numbers are jquery objects... Its test data... Wasn't going to paste in a whole object and expect people to just do it... Thats just lazy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short approach with `Array.reduce` and `Array.filter`:

Basically it starts with the first array as start value for the reduce. Then the result set is filtered by the lookup of the indices, and if found, the value remains, otherwise the value is skipped. This continues until the object has no more property.

```js
var filter = {
    x: [1, 3, 5, 6],
    y: [1, 4, 7, 8],
    z: [1, 9]
};

var filtered = Object.keys(filter).reduce(function (r, a, i) {
    return i ? r.filter(function (b) {
        return ~filter[a].indexOf(b);
    }) : filter[a];
}, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Bonus with objects, returns the common key/s:

```js
var filter = {
    x: { a: 'ah', c: 'ce', e: 'eh', f: 'ef' },
    y: { a: 'ah', d: 'de', g: 'ge', h: 'ha' },
    z: { a: 'ah', i: 'ie' }
};

var filtered = Object.keys(filter).reduce(function (r, a, i) {
    return i ? r.filter(function (b) {
        return b in filter[a];
    }) : Object.keys(filter[a]);
}, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I would do this in 2 parts:

1 Find the common items

2 Extract the common items

```
var filter = {
    x : [1,3,5,6],
    y : [1,4,7,8],
    z : [1,9]
}

// Find the common
var common;
Object.keys(filter).forEach(function (k) {
    if (common) {
         for (var i=0; i<common.length; i++) {
             // Check if the common value exists on the key
             if (filter[k].indexOf(common[i]) === -1) {
                 // If it does not, it is not common
                 common.splice(i, 1);
                 i--;
             }
         }
    } else {
        // On the first item, we assume all are common
        common = filter[k]
    }
})

// Additional processing can take place to extract the data you need here
//Should print "[1]"
console.log(common)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution: **Here I used the same structure of your data, without converting it to arrays**

HTML

```
<p id="result"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
var value = 'value',
    filter = {
        x : {1:value,3:value,5:value,6:value,9:value},
        y : {1:value,4:value,7:value,8:value,9:value},
        z : {1:value,9:value}
    };

function getCommon(data) {
    var subObjects = [],
        common = [];

    if(typeof data === 'object'){

        // collect all sub-keys into an array
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
            if(typeof data[key] === 'object') {
                subObjects = subObjects.concat(Object.keys(data[key]));
            }
        });

        // get the common keys
        Object.keys(data[Object.keys(data)[0]]).forEach(function(subKey){
            if(getCount(subObjects, subKey) === Object.keys(data).length) {
                common.push(subKey);
            }
        });

        function getCount(data, target){
            return data.filter(function(item){
                return item === target;
            }).length;
        }

        return common;
    }
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = getCommon(filter);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/bbnbfck7/